Horror movie anthology with a story about bomber crew
I remember seeing this movie on TV as a kid, so about 20 years ago, but I can't really recall much of the plot points. 
It was a horror movie anthology and had 3 or 4 short stories. One of them was about a crew of B-52-style bomber (flying fortress), the entire story took place during their flight and there were some supernatural things happening. 
I'm not sure if it was set during WW2 or the Cold War, but the ending of that story was the plane crashing on some island.
EDIT: It was not an animated movie.

There was an anthology series called Amazing Stories that had an episode with a bomber.  If I remember, the landing gear was broken and someone drew things in a sketch book that happened in real life, so he was able to draw some landing gear.  The show also had horror/thrilled themed episodes.

It might be an episode of the TV anthology series created by Steven Spielberg Amazing Stories (1985-1987), called "The Mission". It's season 1, episode 5.  (IMDB- Serie / IMDB - The mission)
Wikipedia:
"Three of the episodes ("The Mission", "Mummy Daddy" and "Go to the Head of the Class") were packaged together as an anthology film and released theatrically in several European countries such as Spain, France (July 10, 1986) or Finland (June 26, 1987), and also in Australia on September 17, 1987. It later appeared on LaserDisc in Japan as Amazing Stories: The Movie shortly afterwards".
"The Mission"


"Go to the Head of the Class"

"Mummy Daddy"

Amazing Stories movie commercial
Amazing Stories 1x05 - The Mission

Great, this is it. Thanks for answer!

Heavy Metal, (1981).

The film is an anthology of various science fiction and fantasy
  stories adapted from Heavy Metal magazine and original stories in the
  same spirit.
...
B-17
A World War II B-17 bomber nicknamed the "Pacific Pearl" makes a
  difficult bombing run with heavy damage and casualties. As the bomber
  limps home, the co-pilot goes back to check on the crew. Finding
  nothing but dead bodies, he notices the Loc-Nar trailing the plane.
  Informing the pilot, he heads back to the cockpit, when the Loc-Nar
  rams itself into the plane and reanimates the dead crew members as
  zombies. The co-pilot is killed, while the pilot parachutes away in
  time. He lands on an island where he finds a graveyard of airplanes
  from various times, along with the wrecked airplanes' zombified
  airmen.

The scene is on Youtube.

Thanks for answer. It's amazing that this seems to be perfectly accurate, but I'm 100% sure that the movie I'm looking for was not animated.
